# How to initialize all integers in an array in Java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, initialization

Is there a predefined function in Java to set all integers in an array to a specified value?

Suppose the following array is given: `byte start[][][] = new byte[MAXSUM][rows][N * 2];` Is there any nicer way than `3 loops` to initialize it to some constant, other than `0`?

Can `Arrays.fill()` be used to initialize values in an array with more than 1 dimension?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no built-in for that, but it shouldn't look very ugly to do it with nested for loops.

```
public static void multiDimensionalFill(byte[][][] start, byte value) {
    for(byte[][] firstdim : start)
        for(byte[] seconddim : firstdim)
            Arrays.fill(seconddim, value);
}
```

Comment: Compared to C/C++ `memset(start, -1, sizeof(start))` one-liner it does look cumbersome...

Comment: @Leonid unfortunately Java isn't C or C++ and you don't have access to the low-level memory of an array reference. However, you can simply create a few static utility methods in your project and then simply call into the `multiDimensionalFill` whenever you need to initialize something - problem solved.

Comment: Well nobody stops you from using a one dimensional array and just calling Arrays.fill on that and doing the translation from 1 to n-dimensions per access. That's exchanging a minor inconvience against a sligher larger but would "work" ;)

Comment: Do you know reasons for why Java libraries do not provide this functionality? Especially for simple types it would be very useful, and perhaps more efficient library implementation can be written.

Answer (score 1):

There is no nicer, built-in way to initialize a multi-dimensional array other than looping over the values.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays.fill() works only for one dimension arrays